# Show List values by pageblock table

Tags: apex, visualforce

Please let me know how to display list values in apex page by page block table format.

I have this piece of code.

```
    <apex:dataList value="{!my_list}" var="c">
      {!c.Name},{!c.Account_OAPI__c}
</apex:dataList>

</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Use <apex:pageBlockTable> component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really just a take a look at the documentation on PageBlockTable as it covers it pretty well.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm

The general premise is if you have a list of any object that is accessible from your controller, you can use that list in a PageBlockTable like this

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!your_list}" var="i">
    <apex:column value="{!i.Field_1}"/> 
    <apex:column value="{!i.Field_2}"/> 
    <apex:column value="{!i.Field_3}"/> 
    <apex:column value="{!i.Field_x}"/> 
    <apex:column value="{!i.Field_x+1}"/> 
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```